# How would a supernatural boiling sea in the Southern Ocean affect Earth's climate?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, climate-change, tectonics, sea

How would a boiling sea in the southern ocean near Antarctica affect Earth's climate? This boiling sea was caused by supernatural forces providing the energy to boil the water while also keeping it from expanding.

[image: This picture represents the size, length and location of the boiling sea.]

This picture represents the size of the "Boiling Sea" caused by this supernatural force.

What effects would this supernatural, constantly boiling ocean have on the Earth?

Comment: (a) Technically this is an off-topic [High Concept Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) (you introduce a single change and want to know planet-wide results). These violate a number of our rules (see the [tour], [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). (b) You haven't provided enough detail: what's the longitude/latitude of the affected sea? Is is salinated? (c) This is a limited time issue as enough magma will eventually boil off all the water. Boil it slow and it'll create extra fog. Boil it fast and it'll create somethng (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... a bit worse. Eventually the physical area the magma must expand into is effected by the expanding influence of water that it's cooled and no more boiling takes place. (d) Which is a long way of saying that, due to the [tag:science-based] tag, you won't have a long enough term solution to materially affect ocean currents and atmospheric weather only a titch. If you choose to switch to [tag:science-fiction] and declare the heat source to be infinitely capable but unable to expand (so that your boiling sea remains limited) (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Then we might have enough to work with... if it survives the judgement as to whether or not it's a High Concept Question.

Comment: even if you peeled open the entire artic ocean the effect would not last even a year, you really underestimate how much water is in the ocean and how quickly it will cool lava. hundreds of miles of lava are in contact with ocean ever day at mid ocean ridges. what you are talking about already happens on earth. exposed magma is cooled into solid basalt sealing over the magma, its called a flood basalt and has happened efore.

Comment: *"Heating up the ocean enough that it's now constantly steaming":* That won't happen with any kind of reasonable heat source. Water is really really very good at conducting heat away. For example, there is a 20,000 km (12,000 miles) long diverging boundary going right through the middle of the Atlantic, widening the ocean by about 2.5 cm (1 *Zoll*) per year; the Atlantic is not "constantly steaming".

Comment: Please actually edit your question. Don't just append additional text. It makes it difficult to understand what you're currently asking. If anyone wants to know how the question has changed over time they can read the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a planetary crust as human skin, and magma flowing from volcanoes as the pus that comes out of acne when you pop a zit. It's normal (for some values of normal) to have some here and there, but if you have an area on your body that lacks an epidermis and is just pus flowing constantly, then something is obviously very broken.

> Because of this disaster, an oceanic plate and continental plate started to diverge (...)

This is something that happens in real life, but with much less dramatic outcomes. We only get hydrothermal vents from that.

> This divergence caused huge amounts of lava to flow from the mantle, heating up the ocean enough that it's now constantly steaming (...)

The average depth of the Atlantic is about 3,300 meters (for people with a foot fetish, that's about 10,000 feet). [Detonating nukes in sequence from the bottom of the ocean might not achieve this effect you describe](https://what-if.xkcd.com/15/). In order for that to happen, we would need some really planet-breaking event - the kind that would probably turn the Earth into a Venus-like world at best, or cause it to eventually lose its atmosphere at worst. To put it into perspective: the asteroid that killed dinosaurs left a crater big enough to be visible on a world map, sent shockwaves across the globe, did a real number on global weather, but didn't make a dent on the crust. But supposing we get hit by a larger rock...

The last time the Earth had a considerable portion of its surface covered by magma was the [Hadean eon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadean)  when it was cooling down from forming. According to the wiki:

> (...) The initial heavy atmosphere had a surface temperature of 230 °C (446 °F) and an atmospheric pressure of above 27 standard atmospheres.

So there's your weather.

Comment: actually what is described has happened before they are called flood basalt, but you are right it will cool in a very short amount of time.